# ImportError: cannot import name 'create_player'

Tags: python, attributeerror

This is my first time on here so I'm sorry if I forget something.

I'm trying to make this text-based rpg game. I have 2 different files: rpg and character_file. rpg is the main file which calls the other functions. I haven't copied across the whole code because there's over a 1000 lines so if I need to add anything please let me know.

So this is the one from rpg:

```
import time
import gui
import character_file
import battle
import random

#mode, race and char_name have been defined in another function.
def create_player(mode, race, char_name):
 if mode == 2:
  if race == 1:
   player = Character.Goblin(char_name, app)
  elif race == 2:
   player = Character.Orc(char_name, app)
  elif race == 3:
   player = character.Uruk(char_name, app)
  elif race == 4:
   player = character.Wizard(char_name, app)
  else:  
   player = character.Troll(char_name, app)
 else:
  if race == 1:
   player = character.Elf(char_name, app)
  elif race == 2:
   player = character.Dwarf(char_name, app)
  elif race == 3:
   player = character.Human(char_name, app)
  elif race == 4:
   player = character.Hobbit(char_name, app)
  else:
   player = character.Wizard(char_name, app)
 return player

...

player = create_player(mode, race, char_name)
```

and this is the character_file:

```
import time
import random
import rpg

...


class Character:
 defines main character attributes

class Dwarf(Character, app):
 Character.__init__(self, char_name, app)
 defines Dwarf attributes
```

When I run this, it comes up with a AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'character'

I'm sorry if the code's messy and if I'm missing anything. Thank you in advance!

Update: Sorry. Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Documents\School\IT\Python_RPG - Copy\rpg.py", line 12, in <module>
    import character_file
  File "F:\Documents\School\IT\Python_RPG - Copy\character_file.py", line 12, in <module>
    import rpg
  File "F:\Documents\School\IT\Python_RPG - Copy\rpg.py", line 600, in <module>
    player = create_player(mode, race, char_name)
  File "F:\Documents\School\IT\Python_RPG - Copy\rpg.py", line 169, in create_player
    player = character_file.character.Elf(char_name, app)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'character'
```

Comment: Could you please post the traceback?

Comment: You imported `character_file` but use `character` if it's not an example - probably error is here. Also, you can import in this way `from character_file import *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's only a typo (uppercase "C").

You should rename your `character_file.py` in `character` (or `characters`).

This module contains a collections of classes:

```
class Character:
    # [...]
    pass


class Dwarf(Character):
    # A sub-class of Character
    # [...]
    pass
```

To import the classes you must write:

```
import character  # or import characters

player = character.Dwarf(char_name, app)
```

This declaration is wrong:

```
class Dwarf(Character, app):
```

⇨ You don't inherit the `app`.

Your constructor should have the following signature:

```
class Dwarf(Character):
    def __init__(self, char_name, app):
        super(Dwarf, self).__init__(char_name, app)
        # more init here
```